# KmlLayer with Schema in ArcGIS API for Silverlight?

Tags: kml, arcgis-silverlight-api

I have a KML file I'd like to load with the KmlLayer in my Silverlight application. The problem is that the markup seems more complicated than the class wants to handle. I have a  element at the top of the Document that adds custom elements () and for some reason changes the  element name to a custom one.

I've been searching for a couple days but no one seems to have covered this issue. Has anyone here come across a option or somesuch you can set so that the KmlLayer notices and adheres to the  elements customizations?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the 2.2 spec has dropped this strange @parent attribute from Schema. Why you would want to rename `<Placemark>` is beyond me anyway... In addition, custom elements are supported in `KmlLayer` with `<ExtendedData>` and not `<Schema>`... Looks like I'll have to consult the KML author about how they're formatting things.

```
<Schema name="string" id="ID">
  <SimpleField type="string" name="string">
    <displayName>...</displayName>            <!-- string -->
  </SimpleField>
</Schema>
```

The short answer it seems is that the WmsLayer as of API v2.4 really only supports custom elements implemented via the `<ExtendedData>` tag. You can access this information with some tricky code that handles [Toolkit.DataSources.Kml.KmlExtendedData](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.Kml.KmlExtendedData.html) class.